# Post being added to another user's posts when signing in

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that allows users to make posts. I am noticing that when a user makes a `post`, the post is correctly added to their `posts`. However, when that user signs out and I sign in a different user, that `post` is appended to the new signed in user's `posts`. So, the same post is present on two users' `posts`. I cannot figure out how this went wrong. I have tried using breakpoints but I'm not even finding where the code could possibly be doing this. The code to add the post is:

```
@IBAction func postButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {


            guard let beverageNameAdd = beverageName.text, beverageNameAdd != "" else {
                print("ERIC: Caption must be entered")
                return
            }

            if bevCat == "Wine" {
                guard let wineVintageAdd = wineVintage.text, wineVintageAdd != "" else {
                    print("ERIC: Vintage must be entered")
                    return
                }

                self.wineCount = self.wineCount + 1
                db.collection("users").document(uid!).setData([ "wineCount": self.wineCount!], merge: true)
            }

            if bevCat == "Beer" {
                self.beerCount = self.beerCount + 1
                db.collection("users").document(uid!).setData([ "beerCount": self.beerCount!], merge: true)
            }

            if bevCat == "Liquor" {
                self.liquorCount = self.liquorCount + 1
                db.collection("users").document(uid!).setData([ "liquorCount": self.liquorCount!], merge: true)
            }

             guard let beverageTypeAdd = beverageType.text, beverageTypeAdd != "" else {
                print("ERIC: Vintage must be entered")
                return
            }

            guard let img = newPostImage.image, imageSelected == true else {
                print("ERIC: An image must be selected")
                return
            }



            if let imageData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) {

                let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString
                let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
                let storageItem = STORAGE_BASE.child(imgUid)
                print("STORAGE ID: \(storageItem)")


                DataService.ds.REF_POST_IMAGES.child(imgUid).putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("ERIC: Unable to upload image to Firebasee torage")
                    } else {
                        print("ERIC: Successfully uploaded image to Firebase storage")
                        DataService.ds.REF_POST_IMAGES.child(imgUid).downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print("ERROR in image \(error!)")
                                print("Error URL for image: \(String(describing: url))")
                                return
                            }
                            if url != nil {
                                self.postToFirebase(imgUrl: url!.absoluteString)
                                print("URL for image: \(String(describing: url))")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "reloadFeed", sender: self)
        }

        func postToFirebase(imgUrl: String) {
            let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
                //"postTimeStamp":  [".sv" : "timestamp"] as AnyObject,
                "beverageName": beverageName.text! as AnyObject,
                "imageUrl": imgUrl as AnyObject,
                "beverageType": beverageType.text! as AnyObject,
                "wineVintage": wineVintage.text! as AnyObject,
                "beverageRating": beverageRating.rating as AnyObject,
                "beveragePrice": beveragePrice.text! as AnyObject,
                "beverageCategory": bevCat as AnyObject,
                "uid": uid as AnyObject
            ]


            let firebasePost = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId()
            firebasePost.setValue(post)
            let userPost = firebasePost.key

            print("Firebase Post: \(String(describing: firebasePost))")

            let followerList = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid!)").child("followers")

            followerList.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                    for snap in snapshot {
                        print("SNAP -- \(snap.key)")

                        DataService.ds.REF_TIMELINE.child("\(snap.key)").child("\(userPost!)").setValue(true)
                    }
                }
            })

            print("ADDING POST \(userPost!)")
            _ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth,user) in
                if let user = user {
                    let userId = user.uid
                    print("USER: \(String(describing: userId))")
                    let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(userId)").child("posts").child(userPost!)
                    newPost.setValue(true)

                }
            }

            beverageName.text = ""
            beverageType.text = ""
            beveragePrice.text = ""
            imageSelected = false
            newPostImage.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-camera-100")

        }
```

Then, the code to sign out is here:

```
@IBAction func logoutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
            let _: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: KEY_UID)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "signOut", sender: self)
        }
        catch let signOutError as NSError {
          print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
}
```

Then the code to login is here:

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let email = emailInput.text, let pwd = passwordInput.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pwd) { [weak self] user, error in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            if let user = user {
                let uid = user.user.uid
                let userData = ["provider": user.user.providerID]
                self!.completeSignIn(id: uid, userData: userData)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Email/Password Incorrect", message: "The username/password combination is incorrect. Try again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                self!.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is probably more required to diagnose this issue but it appears to me based on the Firebase realtime database that the old user's post is appended right when the new user signs in. Has anyone seen this type of behavior before or have any idea how I can begin to debug this?

Comment: Well, kinda guesswork on my part but you've got this `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener` which calls this 'newPost.setValue(true)' so sure enough when the auth state changes, data is written.

Comment: @Jay Right. That is where the code is adding the post to the current user's post when the post button is pressed.

Comment: It's also getting called when the auth state changes.... hence why it's being written again when another user logs in because that changes the auth state.

Comment: @Jay Oh wow. I didn't realize that. I don't want that behavior. Do I even need `_ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener` ? I just want to add the post when the user presses the add post button.

Comment: Just tested and when I just run `let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid)").child("posts").child(userPost!)
                    newPost.setValue(true)` I get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as pointed out by @Jay was with

```
    _ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth,user) in
        if let user = user {
            let userId = user.uid
            print("USER: \(String(describing: userId))")
            let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(userId)").child("posts").child(userPost!)
            newPost.setValue(true)

        }
    }
```

I was adding the post to a user's posts anytime the auth changed which doesn't make any sense. I only need to add the post when the user presses add post. I eliminated all of that code with the exception of:

`let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid)").child("posts").child(userPost!)
newPost.setValue(true)`

Comment: Glad I could help!